# selecting randomly images from 40 images and displaying them in game application in android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android game application.I have implemented the all the basic functionality.Designed all the screens.Now the main problem i am struck is I have to select 25 images randomly from 40 images.And display all the 25 images in the application.Can anyone guide me,,,, Thanks in advance

Regards
Tushar Sahni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have all drawables in your drawable folder for imageview.

See the below implementation I have done in my app. First take Imageview array and int array with length of number of images you have.

```
ImageView i[]=new ImageView[49]; 
int id[]={R.drawable.pic1,......,R.drawable.pic40};
```

Then take arraylist like below and add no 1 to 40 to it.

```
ArrayList<Integer> ranArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<(40);i++)
{
    ranArr.add(i);
}
```

Then shuffle it so your randomness will generate.

```
Collections.shuffle(ranArr);
```

Now your random no logic is over so you can now use that to imageview like below

```
for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        i[i]=(ImageView)findViewById(id[ranArr.get[i]);
    }
```

So it will generate random images from your 40 drawables.

Answer (score 0):

use `Random` class to generate 25 numbers, which are less than 40. Then get the images with generated numbers.

Comment: Thanks for ur coordination Vladmir,,whats ur skype id